# Is std::string an object?

Tags: c++, string, stdmap

just looking in optimizing some `std::map` code. The map contains objects, accessed via the string-identifier.

Example:

```
std::map<std::string, CVeryImportantObject> theMap;

...

theMap["second"] = new CVeryImportantObject();
```

Now, when using the find-function as `theMap->find("second")`, the String is converted into `std::string("second")`, which causes new string allocations (over all when using IDL=2 with Visual Studio).

**1. Is there a possibility to use a string-only class to avoid such allocations?**

Intentionally I've tried to use another String-Class as well:

```
std::map<CString, CVeryImportantObject> theMap;
```

This code works also. But CString *indeed is* an object.

And: If you remove an object from the map, I'll need to release both the related object and the key, do I?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You seem to be using the word "object" in a very confused manner. Do you essentially mean that you want a type for the key that allows you to use string literals without extra allocations? You first example won't compile anyway, since the map stores a `CVeryImportantObject`, but you give it a `CVeryImportantObject*`. (Are you a recovering Java programmer by any chance - `new` is very different between the two languages).

Comment: What is a *string-only* class ? Isn't `std::string` the best possible example of such a class ?

Comment: In C++14 this is fixed AFAIK by using `std::map<std::string, CVeryImportantObject, std::less<>>`.

Comment: You may use a [`std::hash<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash) as key.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That doesn't guarantee that different strings will hash to different values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, when using the find-function as theMap->find("second"), the
>   String is converted into std::string("second"), which causes new
>   string allocations (over all when using IDL=2 with Visual Studio).

This is a Standard issue, which is fixed in C++14 for *ordered* containers. The newest version of VS, VS 14 CTP (which is a *pre-release*) contains [a fix for this issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm), as will new versions of other implementations.

If you need to avoid allocations, you can try a class like `llvm::StringRef` which can refer to `std::string` or string literals interchangably, but then you will be left trying to handle the ownership externally.

You can try something like `unique_ptr<char[], maybe_delete>` that sometimes deletes the contents. This is a bit of a mess to interface with though.

> And: If you remove an object from the map, I'll need to release both
>   the related object and the key, do I?

The map will automatically destruct the key and value for you. For a class which frees it's own resources like `std::string`, which is the only sane way to write C++, then you can erase without worrying about resource cleanup.

Comment: Is the deletion-behavior the same when using `std::map<CString, CVeryImportantObject>` instead of `std::map<std::string, CVeryImportantObject>`?

Comment: Yes, it's true for all std::maps.

Answer (score 0):

If you always use string constants as keys, you can use `const char *` as key type in map when you use proper comparator:

```
struct PCharCompare {
    bool operator()( const char *s1, const char *s2 ) const { return strcmp( s1, s2 ) < 0; }
}; 

std::map< const char *, CVeryImportantObject, PCharCompare> theMap;
```

Note: you have to be careful and need to understand how it works, as it can easily lead to UB:

```
void foo() {
    char buffer[256];
    snprintf( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), "blah" );
    theMap.insert( std::make_pair( buffer, Object ) );
} // ups dangled pointer in the map
```

As for optimization, it is very unlikely that `std::string` creation is a culprit. you may try to use `std::unordered_map` or something similar for optimization

Comment: overloaded `operator ()` can't be static.

Answer (score -1):

> Now, when using the find-function as theMap->find("second"), the
>   String is converted into std::string("second"), which causes new
>   string allocations

Not necessarily. VC uses Small-String Optimisation (SSO). This means that for a string as short as `"second"`, no allocation on the heap should take place at all; the characters will instead be stored directly in the temporarily created `std::string` object.

This is still not free (because the `std::string` has to be created, albeit without any dynamic allocation happening inside), but should be good enough. Is it really a concern for you? Chances are very high that it does not cause any *measurable* performance decrease.

> 1. Is there a possibility to use a string-only class to avoid such allocations?

Not really, except of the C++14 fix mentioned in other answers. Using `char const *` as the key type is very dangerous, because `std::map` will only store the actual addresses, not copies of the keys.

If I were you and if I really experienced performance problems, I'd just not use `std::map` directly but create my own container class to wrap a `std::map<char const *, T, CustomComparison>` and do the hard pointer work inside.

```
template <class ValueType>
class FastStringMap
{
private:

    struct Comparison
    {
        bool operator()(char const *lhs, char const *rhs) const
        {
            return strcmp(lhs, rhs) > 0;
        }
    };

    typedef std::map<char const *, ValueType, Comparison> WrappedMap;

    WrappedMap m_map;

public:
    typedef typename WrappedMap::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename WrappedMap::const_iterator const_iterator;

    bool insert(char const *key, ValueType const &value)
    {
        if (m_map.find(key) != m_map.end())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            char *copy = new char[strlen(key) + 1];
            strcpy(copy, key);

            try
            {
                return m_map.insert(std::make_pair(copy, value)).second;
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                delete copy;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    ~FastStringMap()
    {
        for (iterator iter = m_map.begin(); iter != m_map.end(); ++iter)
        {
            delete[] iter->first;
        }
    }

    iterator find(char const *key)
    {
        return m_map.find(key);
    }

    const_iterator find(char const *key) const
    {
        return m_map.find(key);
    }

    // further operations
};
```

To be used like this:

```
FastStringMap<int> m;
m.insert("AAA", 1);
m.insert("BBB", 2);
m.insert("CCC", 3);
std::cout << m.find("AAA")->second;
```

Note that you can possibly make this more sophisticated by templatising also on the character type (for `std::wstring` support) or by providing "real" iterator classes (using Boost Iterator Facade).

> And: If you remove an object from the map, I'll need to release both
>   the related object and the key, do I?

If you use `std::string`, no. If you use `char const *` and if the pointers point to memory allocated dynamically (as in my example), then yes.

Comment: That's a nice mention of SSO there.

Comment: Your `insert` will leak `copy` if the key is already in the map.

Comment: Sorry, I trivially edited your answer so I could reverse my upvote. Whilst I agree with the spirit of your answer, for God's sake man, at least use a ptr, size pair, even if not begin, end, instead of C-string handling.

Comment: You are right, I guess the code example should have been more comprehensive or just explain the general idea rather than giving the illusion of being copy-n-pastable as it is.

Comment: @Puppy: Not sure about using a ptr/size or begin/end pair (for `insert`, I suppose). It would put a certain burden on the caller. As it is, you can just pass in a simple string literal.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I didn't mean for the interface itself (although adding such overloads would be desirable). I just meant in your implementation in general. Not to mention the lack of `unique_ptr<char[]>`.